# Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations for NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

So I have a lot of data, from the following type:

```
{{3000000, 143758}, {2800000, 142708}, {2600000, 141507}, {2400000, 
  140041}, {2200000, 138615}, {2000000, 137027}, {1800000, 
  134873}, {1600000, 132776}, {1400000, 129637}, {1200000, 
  126212}, {1000000, 121617}}
```

When I try to do the following:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a - b*x^(-1/c), {{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 2}}, x];
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NonlinearModelFit::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
```

I tried to vary the starting values and the Formular by setting `(-1/c) to -c` sometimes it makes the fit better, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Just add `MaxIterations -> \[Infinity]`

Comment: Thank you, now it is working!